# React native just run once, now it's giving me errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been following this link:https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

On react native cli, then windows. I am using vscode, but I can use android studio if needed. I've came to the:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Then I run:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

It worked only once, on my own phone it showed the starting screen. Then I couldn't get it to work again.

**I solved this**: Changing one thing inside gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip this was 6.2, I chaned to 6.3 then it solved itself.
```

Here is the logs:

```
PS C:\Users\Emre\Documents\Demo\AwesomeProjecttest> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 826ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Emre\Documents\Demo\AwesomeProjecttest
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "react-native "run-android""

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-01T21_57_28_233Z-debug.log
```

Comment: In the last line it references and error log file, does that file have anything useful?

Comment: I solved this. I changed one thing inside gradle-wrapper.properties:
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
this was 6.2, I chaned to 6.3 then it solved itself.

Comment: Do you mind if I rollback your edit and you add the solution as an answer to your question? Now the question does not make sense in its actual version.

Comment: Well code is nothing much, it's just basic react default app, with a few codes different. If you think that will help people more okay then. I found the solution in this site aswell.